# How can I prevent listing content items in Orchard admin that users dont have permissions for?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Been working on some permissions / authentication extensions on a site where different users/roles can only view and edit specific content. Even when using the ContentPermissions module, items which a user does not have view and edit rights on are still enumerated in the /Admin/Content/List page (and then when you click on it, you get access denied)

Is there any way to prevent this from happening altogether? I dug around in the source and it doesn't look like it takes permissions into consideration at that stage, at all:

from **Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers.AdminController.cs**:

```
public ActionResult List(ListContentsViewModel model, PagerParameters pagerParameters) {
        Pager pager = new Pager(_siteService.GetSiteSettings(), pagerParameters);

        var query = _contentManager.Query(VersionOptions.Latest, GetCreatableTypes(false).Select(ctd => ctd.Name).ToArray());

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.TypeName)) {
            var contentTypeDefinition = _contentDefinitionManager.GetTypeDefinition(model.TypeName);
            if (contentTypeDefinition == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            model.TypeDisplayName = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contentTypeDefinition.DisplayName)
                                        ? contentTypeDefinition.DisplayName
                                        : contentTypeDefinition.Name;
            query = query.ForType(model.TypeName);
        }

        switch (model.Options.OrderBy) {
            case ContentsOrder.Modified:
                //query = query.OrderByDescending<ContentPartRecord, int>(ci => ci.ContentItemRecord.Versions.Single(civr => civr.Latest).Id);
                query = query.OrderByDescending<CommonPartRecord>(cr => cr.ModifiedUtc);
                break;
            case ContentsOrder.Published:
                query = query.OrderByDescending<CommonPartRecord>(cr => cr.PublishedUtc);
                break;
            case ContentsOrder.Created:
                //query = query.OrderByDescending<ContentPartRecord, int>(ci => ci.Id);
                query = query.OrderByDescending<CommonPartRecord>(cr => cr.CreatedUtc);
                break;
        }

        model.Options.SelectedFilter = model.TypeName;
        model.Options.FilterOptions = GetCreatableTypes(false)
            .Select(ctd => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(ctd.Name, ctd.DisplayName))
            .ToList().OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value);

        var pagerShape = Shape.Pager(pager).TotalItemCount(query.Count());
        var pageOfContentItems = query.Slice(pager.GetStartIndex(), pager.PageSize).ToList();

        var list = Shape.List();
        list.AddRange(pageOfContentItems.Select(ci => _contentManager.BuildDisplay(ci, "SummaryAdmin")));

        dynamic viewModel = Shape.ViewModel()
            .ContentItems(list)
            .Pager(pagerShape)
            .Options(model.Options)
            .TypeDisplayName(model.TypeDisplayName ?? "");

        // Casting to avoid invalid (under medium trust) reflection over the protected View method and force a static invocation.
        return View((object)viewModel);
    }
```

At no stage does it look like permissions are checked.

I don't really want to edit the default Orchard modules; are there any other extensibility points that I'm missing, or any ideas from anyone else (or do I have to bite the bullet and just edit AdminController?)

Comment: You should be able to override the route to the content list and redirect it to your own action where you can add permissions. And honestly, it is not like each new version of Orchard doesn't pose a host of problems in upgrading so modifying a little bit of core code shouldn't matter that much in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Alternatively (and probably terrible practise and crap for performance), you may(?) be able to override the view with your own and add permissions there...

Comment: I believe that the first alternative is the best. Override this action, adding a custom controller with the permissions check logic.